# Big table sqoop import to hive, fixed mapper less rows fetch

Tags: mysql, performance, sqoop

I wanna sqoop big table in mysql.
this table has about 300,000,000 rows and operating.

I wanna sqoop as soon as possible, not burden to system.
So, my sqoop command is

```
sqoop import \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://.... \
    --username ... \
    --password ... \
    --query "SELECT * FROM table_name where \$CONDITIONS" \
    --hive-import \
    --hive-overwrite \
    --hive-table ........ \
    --create-hive-table \
    --mapreduce-job-name .... \
    --num-mappers $mapper_count \
    --fetch-size $patch_count \
    --split-by "account_id"
```

I want to move all of big table, 500,000 at a time using 100 mappers.

I tried setting num-mappers=100 and fetch-size=500000. But only num-mappers adopted. So, operating Database stressed moving 3,000,000 rows each mappers.

Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess -- cut both the 100 and 500K in half to speed up the sqoop.

Comment: @Rick James I wanna know that why.

Comment: MySQL bogs down when you have 100 connections active at the same time.